# Automatically insert timestamp if there isn't any in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I have a long list of timestamps and there could be chances of timestamps missing for an entire day or days and I want to insert a single timestamp for that particular day

For example if there is no timestamp for 2014-04-04 I want it to insert 2014-04-04 00:00:00 for that particular day.

Can this be done in mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

Add a trigger for after insert to the table.  Make the trigger insert the current timestamp if none has been provided.

Or change the column to have a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Those don't resolve the problem of previous entries having no values, but it does fix the problem for the future.  Filling in the rest should be a straightforward update:  `update mytable set its_timestamp = date(datefield) where its_timestamp is NULL`.

Comment: I want it to add a timetstamp for the missing date not the current timestamp